# Django prevent users from editing their own record in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

In Django I have model called Loans. I want users to be able to edit a loan created by someone else, but not if they created it themselves.

As a bonus, I would like staff members not to be able to edit loans that belong to other staff.

How can I do this? I really have no idea. I tried creating custom validation, then I tried a manger like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from core.models import User


class LoanManager(models.Manager):
    def create_loan(self, request, borrower, approved, start_date, term_in_months, principal, interest_rate_pa, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new loan"""
        print('USER========================================', request.user)

        if borrower != request.user:
            raise ValueError("Staff may not lend to themselves or other staff")

        return super(LoanManager, self).create(borrower=borrower, approved=approved, start_date=start_date, term_in_months=term_in_months, principal=principal, interest_rate_pa=interest_rate_pa,**extra_fields)


class Loans(models.Model):
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    term_in_months = models.IntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(360),
            MinValueValidator(24)
        ])
    principal = models.IntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(1000000),
            MinValueValidator(2000)
        ])
    interest_rate_pa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    objects = LoanManager()
```

Nothing I do seems to prevent users creating loans for themselves and editing them!

Comment: Please fix your code formatting (`{}` button in the editor). You'll have to write such functionality yourself, it's not how admin works.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but I answered a similar question yesterday, I think you could find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191534/add-staff-user-permissions-in-admin-with-custom-user-model/56191659#56191659

Answer (score 0):

Use a mixin with the view.  The example below should check if the current user is the borrower for the Loan object.  If they are the same it prevents access.

```
class MyLoanMixin (object):
    permission_denied_message = "You may not modify your own loan"

    def dispatch (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.get_object().borrower == request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_permission_denied_message(self):
        """
        Override this method to override the permission_denied_message attribute.
        """
        return self.permission_denied_message

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        if self.raise_exception:
            raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
        return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(), self.get_login_url(), self.get_redirect_field_name())
```