# Need to restrict access to view only their inputted data or assigned data in the django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

**User model**

```
class User(models.Model):
    
    
    BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES = (
        
        ('a+','A+'),
        ('a-','A-'),
        ('b+','B+'),
        ('b-','B-'),
        ('ab+','AB+'),
        ('ab-','AB-'),
        ('o+','O+'),
        ('o-','O-')
        
    )
    
    
    BILLABLE_and_NON_BILLABLE_CHOICES=(
        
        
        ('Billable','Billable'),
        ('Non-Billable','Non-Billable')
    )



    employee_name = models.OneToOneField(Default_User,on_delete=CASCADE)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=25,default=None)
    pancard=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    aadhar=models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    personal_email_id=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    emergency_contact_no=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    emergency_contact_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    relation=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    blood_group=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES,null=True)  
    designation=models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="designation")
    billable_and_non_billable=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BILLABLE_and_NON_BILLABLE_CHOICES,default='Billable')
    joining_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    relieving_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table ='User'
        
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**Job model**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    
    job_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='client',default=None)
    #project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='project',default=None)
    project = ChainedForeignKey(Project,chained_field="client", chained_model_field="client",show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='user',default=None)
    hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    
    class Meta:
        
        db_table ='Job'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(str(self.id), self.job_name)
```

**admin.py**

```
class StaffAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    '''def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)

        print(f"\nrequest.user : {request.user}\n")

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs

        return qs.filter(user__id=request.user.id)'''

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        user = request.user
        
        if user.is_superuser:
            return qs 
            
        return qs.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
```

**custom user model**

```
class Default_User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', ]
```

I have given a privilege for the staff users to view, edit and delete the Job API, but I need to restrict to view only their job assigned to that users and edit and delete the jobs which the user have added. But in the above code I couldn't able to do it as it is not showing the jobs which is assigned to the specific user by the superuser. kindly help to resolve this issue as I am new to django i was stucked in this method.

Comment: Which field on the Job model stores the user that added the Job and which field stores the user that is assigned to the Job?

Comment: the user field in the Job model is storing the User assigned and in the User model employee_name field it is storing the user that is added. Everything is interconnected..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) Class, you need to register it against the Model you want to apply it to. The ModelAdmin Class is the representation of a model in the admin interface.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Job

class JobModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(user=request.user)

admin.site.register(Job, JobModelAdmin)
```

Comment: getting an error on trying the above code in admin, it is showing as "ValueError at /admin/App/job/... Cannot query "allwin": Must be "User" instance."  But after i changed the code to (user__id = request.user.id) it is running but not showing any data while logged in as staff user. But i need to get only the user's data or the user adding data.

Comment: I'm not sure about the value error. The above code works for me. It's most likely a permissions error that your user can't view data. You have to explicitly grant the user permissions by adding them to a group, or allocating them the permissions for the model. Also I think you need to add the permissions to the JobModelAdmin class like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56191659/6670570)

Comment: You also need to make sure `myapp` matches your app name or use the correct path for the import of the model. It's not clear what the problem is based on the info provided.